# Using JavaScript, Populate checkboxes on drop-down list change from a text file

Tags: javascript

I have a drop-down list called rcc and some checkbox groups. Here's the HTML code for it.

```
<select id="rcc" name="rcc">
    <option value="Select Your Name">Select Your Name</option>
    <option value="p1">Person 1/option>
    <option value="p2">Person 2</option>
    <option value="p3">Person 3</option>                    
</select>

<input type="checkbox" name="time1[]" value="8:00am"/>8:00am
<input type="checkbox" name="time1[]" value="8:20am"/>8:20am
<input type="checkbox" name="time2[]" value="8:40am"/>8:40am
<input type="checkbox" name="time2[]" value="9:00am"/>9:00am
<input type="checkbox" name="time3[]" value="9:20am"/>9:20am
<input type="checkbox" name="time4[]" value="9:40am"/>9:40am
```

I also have a text file that I've generated that contains the times that I want to be selected when someone selects a different person on the dropdown list. For example, if I choose Person 1, I want to open p1times.txt which looks like:

```
time1
8:00am
time2
8:40am
9:00am
time4
9:40am
```

And then run a script that automatically populates the corresponding checkboxes on the page. I was thinking of looping through the text file, but I'm not sure how the logic would work. Any help would be great :).

Comment: Have you considered storing your data in a format such as JSON?  That would make it much easier to parse the data.

Comment: I don't have any experience with JSON, but I think it might work. Do you know how I would translate my .txt file into JSON, or what it might look like?

Comment: Just like what Bill posted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've posted an example at http://jsfiddle.net/RHUdR/1. I would recommend storing your times as JSON. If you want to place these in a different file, just include that file in your html like any other script file.

The data:

```
var people = {
    p1: { time1: [ '8:00am', '8:20am'], time4: ['9:40am'] },
    p2: { time2: [ '8:40am'], time3: ['9:20am'] },
    p3: { time1: [ '8:00am'], time2: ['9:00am'], time4: ['9:40am' ]}    
};
```

And a little jquery to set the values:

```
$('#rcc').change(function() {
    var person = $(this).val();
    var times = people[person] || [];

    $('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked', false);
    for (var name in times) {
        var bucket = times[name];
        for(var i = 0, len = bucket.length; i < len; i++ ) {
            $('input[name="' + name + '"][value="' + bucket[i] + '"]')
                .attr('checked', true);
        }
    }        
});
```

Comment: Thanks Bill, this a great start but not exactly what I'm looking for. p1(Person 1) can have times on multiple days so for example, I would want when I click Person 1 a checkboxgroup called times1 should select 8am, and then another checkboxgroup called times2 should select both 8:40am and 9:20am. Maybe this code could be modified to support that functionality?

Comment: This code actually works with the html supplied so there are the checkboxgroups that you specified and when the form is submitted you will see times1['8:00am'] and time2['8:40am','9:20am']. Since all of the times are different, there is no reason to encode them that way in the text file or in the code, however. Are their cases when the times could overlap between groups?

Comment: Yes, different times[x] will have the same times. Sorry I wasn't specific about that earlier.

Comment: For some reason, it does not seem to work for me. I uploaded my code to your example, maybe I am making a mistake somewhere?

Comment: First, make sure you are using the updated code, looks like the fiddle is still using the original. Second, the fiddle won't work because it can't find the .js with the times in it (I'm guessing it's sitting locally on your computer). Third, in the fiddle you are never calling `loadTimesNow()` so nothing is actually being executed.

Comment: Alright, it works with one little issue. For some reason, it won't fill in the checkboxes unless I click on Person 1, click on some other menu item, and then click on Person 1 again. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have this behavior in jsfiddle? If not, you'll need to use the debugger and set break points to figure out what's going on. Sounds like something isn't being initialized correctly.

Comment: I looked at the error console and found that It has something to do with my including my .js script. It does not seem to load the first time, and then when I click on it again, it loads my .js script and everything works. I think it may be an asynchronous issue, but I am not sure.

Comment: Probably, you need to wait until it is fully loaded. Try loading it using a normal script tag in your html header. Then it will load before any of the other javascript runs.

Comment: The only problem with that is that the name of the file is dynamically created, so it's looking for var x + times.js using javascript. Is there anyway I could delay the second function from firing or in anyway wait for it to fully load?

Comment: Yes, there are a couple of different ways to do that, but at this point I think we've gotten to a new question entirely than the one you originally posted. Feel free to open a new one.